# Matlab Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached error

Tags: matlab, recursion, quicksort

Hey I am new at Matlab and I wrote a simple code for quicksort but for some arrays mostly longer arrays my recursion fails and gives me the following error:
"Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the
limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or
your computer.

Error in quic"

I think my base case might be wrong but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function A = quicksort(A,left,right)


[A, pivot] = PartitionPivot(A, left, right); %chosen pivot
A = quicksort(A, left, pivot-1); %scan from the left of the array until an element greater than pivot is found and swap it with the element less than the pivot on the right of the pivot
A = quicksort(A, pivot+1, right); %scan from the right of the array until an element less than   pivot is found and swap it with the element greater than the pivot on the left of the pivot
end

function [sortedSub_array,Pivot] = PartitionPivot(Sub_array,left_index,right_index)

% Initialization
S = Sub_array;
left = left_index;
right = right_index;

P = S(left); %pivot
i = left+1;

% Partition
for j = i:right 
    if S(j) < P 
        temp1 = S(j);
        S(j) = S(i);
        S(i) = temp1;
        i = i+1; %increment i only when swap occurs
    end
end
swap1 = S(left);
S(left) = S(i-1);
S(i-1) = swap1;

sortedSub_array = S;
Pivot = P;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is that you did not include a stopping criterion, which means that the algorithm will never stop and indeed exceed any finite limit. Second, you return a pivot VALUE, while you are using the value as a pivot INDEX for the next iteration.

Including a stopping criterion and returning the index i instead of the value P solves your problems:

```
function A = quicksort(A,left,right)


if left < right
    [A, pivot] = PartitionPivot(A, left, right); %chosen pivot
    A = quicksort(A, left, pivot-1); %scan from the left of the array until an element greater than pivot is found and swap it with the element less than the pivot on the right of the pivot
    A = quicksort(A, pivot+1, right); %scan from the right of the array until an element less than   pivot is found and swap it with the element greater than the pivot on the left of the pivot
end

end

function [sortedSub_array,PivotIndex] = PartitionPivot(Sub_array,left_index,right_index)

% Initialization
S = Sub_array;
left = left_index;
right = right_index;

P = S(left); %pivot
i = left+1;

% Partition
for j = i:right
    if S(j) < P 
        temp1 = S(j);
        S(j) = S(i);
        S(i) = temp1;
        i = i+1; %increment i only when swap occurs
    end
end
swap1 = S(left);
S(left) = S(i-1);
S(i-1) = swap1;

sortedSub_array = S;
PivotIndex = i-1;

end
```

By the way, you could shorten your code significantly by using less variables. Including a check for the number of arguments allows you to call quicksort with only the array itself as parameter.

```
function A = quicksort(A,left,right)

if nargin == 1
    left = 1;
    right = numel(A);
end

if left < right
    [A, pivot] = PartitionPivot(A, left, right); %chosen pivot
    A = quicksort(A, left, pivot-1); %scan from the left of the array until an element greater than pivot is found and swap it with the element less than the pivot on the right of the pivot
    A = quicksort(A, pivot+1, right); %scan from the right of the array until an element less than   pivot is found and swap it with the element greater than the pivot on the left of the pivot
end

end

function [A, i] = PartitionPivot(A,left,right)

P = A(left); % pivot

A([right left]) = A([left right]);
i = left;

% Partition
for j = left:right-1
    if A(j) < P 
        A([j i]) = A([i j]);
        i = i+1; % increment i only when swap occurs
    end
end
A([right i]) = A([i right]);

end
```